# Building a token list in lua

Tags: luatex

In TeX, a 'write' node is inserted with, say:

```
\write1{\string\doit{\the\lastypos}}
```

With pure luatex, a node could be created with:

```
local n = node.new(8, 1)
n.stream = 1
n.data = <token-list>
```

According to the manual, the `<token-list>` is a table representing the token list to be written (with a list of triplets). I couldn't find any documentation about how this list is built. I discovered a string is accepted, but it gets converted to a string'ed list of chars (much like \meaning), so `\the\lastypos` is written verbatim, not evaluated.

I've found a workaround, shown in the following piece of code:

```
\setbox0\hbox{\write1{\the\lastxpos}}

\directlua{

  for _,d in ipairs(tex.box[0].head.data) do
    texio.write(' ** ' .. d[1] .. '/' .. d[2] .. '/' .. d[3])
  end

}
```

I define a box with a `\write` and then inspect the node. In the real code, instead of printing it I pass it to `n.data` and primitives work as expected (with some problems in user defined macros).

My question is: how to generate in lua the token list to feed the `data` field? [**Edit**. Please, note my questions is not about `\lastypos`, but about building an arbitrary token list for the `data` field. Remember also that, because of the asynchronous nature of TeX, page numbers and the like are not known when the 'write' node is created, only when the 'write' is actually output.]

Here is a latex file to make some experiments, with a lua file named extra.lua:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\donothing#1{}

\directlua{
  require'extra'
}

\setbox0\hbox{\write1{\string\donothing{\the\lastypos}}}

\begin{document}

\directlua{

for _,d in ipairs(tex.box[0].head.data) do
  texio.write(' +++ ' .. d[1] .. '/' .. d[2] .. '/' .. d[3])
end

}

\copy0
\copy0
\copy0

\end{document}
```

The lua file:

```
local n = node.new(8, 1)
n.stream = 1
n.data =  'abcd#&\\the\\lastxpos' 

for _,d in ipairs(n.data) do
  texio.write(' *** ' .. d[1] .. '/' .. d[2] .. '/' .. d[3])
end
```

Comment: you can use `tex.lastypos` to avoid needing to tex-expand `\the\lastypos` and put the value straight in the whatsit.

Comment: `\lastypos` is just an example. There is no `\savepos` in the examples after all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Furthermore, this would write the value of `lastypos` when the whatsit is created, not when it's output, after a `save_pos` node.

Comment: sure but you could arrange the timing differently, but as you say without any savepos in the example not clear what the timing should be.

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify what I'm asking.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `\latelua` instead of `\directlua` then?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You might need a 'write' inside a callback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LuaTeX has the `token.create` function to create a token uservalue. They can be combined into a token list by putting them into a table. For `\string\donothing{\the\lastvpos}` this would be:

```
tl = {
  token.create'string',
  token.create'donothing',
  token.create(string.byte'{'),
    token.create'the',
    token.create'lastypos',
  token.create(string.byte'}')
}
```

Normally the references to tokenlists in the LuaTeX documentation mean this kind of table, but you need a different kind: A table of tables of numbers. Finding these numbers isn't easy, but you can convert token lists in the format above into this other format (Here I am using a little trick: `{0, v.tok}` is interpreted in the same way as if we would have split `v.tok` properly into three parts):

```
\directlua{
local function convert_tl(list)
  local new = {}
  for i,v in ipairs(list) do
    new[i] = {0, v.tok}
  end
  return new
end

local n = node.new(8, 1)
n.stream = 3
n.data = convert_tl{
  token.create'string',
  token.create'donothing',
  token.create(string.byte'{'),
    token.create'the',
    token.create'lastypos',
  token.create(string.byte'}')
}

tex.box[0] = node.hpack(n)
}
\copy0
\copy0
```

results in the output

```
\donothing{0}
\donothing{0}
```

Comment: Wow! I wouldn't say the `v.tok` is a _little_ trick. But my first tests worked, indeed.

Comment: @JavierBezos A little warning: Do not rely too much on reading the tokenlist, newer LuaTeX version only provide the expanded string if you try to read from `.data`.

Comment: Bad news, except if you can assign a string to `data` (which in turn gets tokenized). Otherwise something like `x.data = y.data` won't work, which is very very counterintuitive.

Comment: A little question: do you know if a deep copy of a 'write' node will preserve the internal structure of the `data` field?